# How can I position two <divs> to always be side by side

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="block-content table">
   <div class="row" style="height: 5rem">
      <div class="cell" id="logo">xxx</div>
      <div class="cell" id="navigation">
         xxxxx
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When displayed full-width then the logo appears to the left and the navigation to right. 
However as I reduce the browser width then the navigation moves to below the logo.

```
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.table {
  display: table;
}

#header-view .top-page .block-content {
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
}
#header-view .top-page .block-content #logo {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 20rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5rem;
}
#header-view .top-page .block-content #navigation {
  height: 5rem;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 5rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  width: 40rem;
}
```

How can I ensure that the logo and navigation always appear side by side? Note I did try and make the #logo and #navigation as "display: inline-block" however this did not seem to help so I tried using css tables but it still did not work.

Comment: add float to each div, float: left for one and float: left to another

Comment: You mean float:left for one and float:right for the other ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/SQ9Hf/2/

You need to put some `float`, and the best thing to do is to put each div with a % width.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS tables will work, but the problem is that you have set the widths in rem, which is relative to font size. if you set them in percentages and adjust the values, the divs will always be a certain proportion of the width of the parent and will resize with the page. Make sure to set the parent's width as well, for example: `width: 100%`